# How do I get the height of a GWT object in pixels?

Tags: gwt

How do I get the height of a GWT object in pixels? I am trying to find a getHeight method or something similar..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`getOffsetHeight()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetHeight()) (inherited by every part of the UI from [`UiObject`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html)):

> Gets the object's offset height in
>   pixels. This is the total height of
>   the object, including decorations such
>   as border, margin, and padding.

There's also the [`getClientHeight()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getClientHeight()) from [`Element`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html):

> Returns the inner height of an element
>   in pixels, including padding but not
>   the horizontal scrollbar height,
>   border, or margin.

You can access the underlying Element of every UiObject (meaning Widgets, etc) via the [`getElement()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getElement()) method.

Be sure to check that the item is visible at the time the size is read, else you will get 0.

Comment: According to the documentation, this should work. In practice however it always returns 0. Do you have an idea what it is so?

Comment: @Sébastien Tromp: It's hard to diagnose the problem with such scarce information ;) I can't recall which CSS properties (`display`? `float`?) can impact the height as seen in the DOM tree. The element might actually have 0 height, but the margin is the "filling"... The are a lot of possibilities - I'd recommend just asking a new question with your problem here on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I don't think it includes the margin.

Comment: It always returns 100 (both width and height). This is not the correct method clearly.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed *getOffsetHeight()* but that just gives the total height of the object, including decorations such as border and padding, **but not margin**.[1](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetHeight%28%29)
You can get the element and use *getClientHeight()* and it gives the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but **not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin**.

So getting the full rendered height including margins don't seem to be possible.